# How to adjust the font size in Ubuntu Software Center?

Tags: software-center, fonts

I like to use the Ubuntu Software Center, but I cannot adjust the font size of the entries. So most of the entries' fonts are so ridiculously small for me that, I can't read them!

I tried by changing system fonts, but that didn't help.

How can I adjust the fonts of the contents in Ubuntu Software Center in Ubuntu 12.04?

Comment: Can you include a screenshot?

Answer (score 3):

A simple solution would be Gnome-Tweak-Tool, also known in the software center as "Advanced Settings". Now you may use this to change the font size affecting the software center, however unfortunately all other applications as well. A recommended way to preform the font change would be to open the settings, change the font size, and then when done with the software center, return it to it's original form, or however you prefer it. If you can't get the application from the software center, due to the small size of the font just paste the following into your terminal -

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool
```

[image: Install via the software center]

Here is what Advanced Settings should appear as, simply click the font size next to the default font to make changes.

[image: Tweak Tool]

Well, you don't really want to mess with the other settings I'm assuming, (Graphics Drivers, or Screen Resolution) But, just to voice other solutions, you could start by seeing if this is the graphics driver, I personally use the open source one because I have no other choice than binary blobs, or the screen resolution could be toned down to make the text appear larger... I hope any of this can help!

Comment: I set the resolution of the screen now to 1440x900. On an original 1920x1200 TFT screen sizes are a bit better now, at least the hardcoded fonts in some places - but now the fonts get blurry. That was to be expected and there is no more possibility to play around with the antialiasing and the dpi values ... so really: either too small or bigger and blurry! great choices ...

Comment: btw: who's doing this font design? in print design you wouldn't want to use more than two fonts and rarely more than 3 different sizes max ... same for usable webdesign - I really wonder if freedom is about choices: why can't I set the fonts in gnome/unity the way I need them manually, really annoying !

Comment: @mateo_salta: thx anyway for your nice answer, but before I posed the question I tried every tool aound there and yes I messed with graphics settings, resolutions and (in KDE) with DPI adjustments, subpixel hinting and so forth. I am not afraid of heavy customization, just I have to know where to find the right screws to turn ... but anyway: nice post, thx a lot!

Comment: @piedro it is flabricorn's answer. I just edited to include the software center link.

Comment: I just checked with the software center in 12.10 - it is even worse: I get about 5 different font-sizes: the left pane is smaller then system font, the prices and categoriy names are about double font-size of the system fonts, the names of the applications are very small (looks smaller than the left pane to me ...) some dialogs seem to be hardcoded or use some different settings also ...

Comment: @piedro Screenshot perhaps? I don't see this problem with mine.

Comment: have you set the fontsize to very big or big in the systemsettings >> accessability settings? p.

Comment: Nope, I haven't been messing with font sizes at all. This is out of the box.